# Possible to force use of English version of some strings in Android

Tags: android, locale

In my app, I use some strings with technical information that can't be accurately translated in some cases. Is it possible to have a check to allow the user to show the related strings in original (English) version? I'm referring to showing all app strings in the device's language (Spanish, French, etc.) and some strings in English (even if the string has a translation).

Comment: Exactly, you can also try to put the english version in spanish. That way, you fool the dalvik: He thinks he is showing the spanish translation, when in fact he is only showing english. And you can do that with probably very low cost because of the compilers' efficiency nowadays (cost will not be more than a couple of kB)

Comment: in the first place, why you need to translate if a particular string cannot be translated accurately?

Comment: Agreed. "I use some strings with technical information that can't be accurately translated in some cases" -- then why do you have a translation? If you remove the translations, then Android will load your default value (presumably English in this case) for all locales.

Comment: I'm refer to show english (default) translation to some strings on the fly, even in your device language is not english and if the app has a translation for it.

Comment: I agree this could be useful. For example, in our app we want to track events in analytics, and I don't want localized strings to be sent to our analytics